# Difference between splitting targeting over several ad groups and keeping whole targeting in one ad group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I will give small example to explain my question: If we have Facebook ad campaign that needs to target Germany and France, would there be any performance difference if we use one ad group with targeting (Germany, France), or we create two adgroups in this campaign where one would target (Germany) and other would target (France) (same ad image and ad creative settings)?

Kind regards,
Nikola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally split targeting for two main reasons.

**1. Controlling Budget**

Segmenting targeting across geographical areas can allow you to control your budget at a more granular level. For example, if you want to spend 30% of your budget on France and 70% on Germany, splitting the targeting will allow you to achieve this by using multiple campaigns.

**2. Understanding Performance**

Segmenting the target also gives you greatr insight into which of your targets are performing the best. For example, if you split your target by age, gender and region, you may identify that shoes sell well to men in France between the ages of 25-30 etc.

Be careful to ensure your use of this data complies with Facebook's policy however: https://www.facebook.com/ad_guidelines.php

**Over-segmentation**

Facebook's algorithms work best when there is a large population within the target. Over segmenting your campaign could result in the overall performance being weaker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

In case I have 1 campaign with 2 ad_groups, comparing to also 1 campaign with 20 ad_groups (same targeting as in 2 ad groups, but split on 20 ad groups) - would there be any performance influence?

Comment: if the adverts do no overlap, then no - again assuming the targets are sufficiently high for oCPM.